# Is my reasoning accurate?

Tags: metric-spaces

$$\text{d}_{H}(A,B)  = \max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A} \inf_{b\in B} \text{d}(a,b),\sup_{b\in B} \inf_{a\in A}\text{d}(a,b)\right\}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are two closed subsets of a metric space $(E,d)$
is a pseudo-distance
if $\text{d}_{h}(A,B)=0 \implies$  the RHS of the above equation is 0
As the maximum of two positive elements is always zero($d(a,b) \geq 0$)
Both the terms inside the max are zero ie
$\sup_{a \in A} \inf_{b \in B} \text{d}_{h}(a,b)=0$
But as the supremum over the elements of $A$ is zero $\implies$

$\inf_{b \in B} \text{d}_{h}(a,b)=0 \implies d(B,a)=0$, where $d(B,a)=0$ is the distance of a point of $a$ from set B(It is defined in such a way) 
and it follows  that $a$ is a contact point of $B$.
But this is true $\forall a \in A$, we have
$\forall a \in A$, we have $ a \in \overline{B}$ where $\overline{B}$ is the set of all contact points of B which is a closed set
 $ \implies A\subset \overline{B}$

Similarly we can show that $$B\subset \overline{A}$$

Now the above two imply that $\overline {A}=\overline{B}$

Clearly I could not prove A=B , following from above line of reasoning. Could someone show me why A is not equal to B?
I can't think of a counter example where $\overline {A}=\overline{B}$ does not imply $A=B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that $A$ and $B$ are closed, as you indicate, then $A = \bar A$ and $B = \bar B$. Thus $A = B$.

If you drop the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are closed, then $d_H$ is just a pseudo-metric. For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} + \sqrt{2}$ are different and at distance zero. Of course they have the same closure.